# How change menu for each user in plugin?

Tags: plugins, menus, users

I need to change navigation menu in my plugin for each user for example:

```
if(is_user_logged_in())
    wp_nav_menu(...);
else
    wp_nav_menu(...);
```

But when I apply the above code in my plugin it shows me some errors. What should I do?

Comment: I want do this in plugin not theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a menu for each type of user in Dashboard >> Appearence >> Menus >> create a new menu (eg http://example.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=0)
Then add a function to your theme's functions.php to switch the menus. Something like as follows:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'wp_nav_menu_args_filter');
function wp_nav_menu_args_filter($args = array()) {
   if (is_user_logged_in) { 
        // Menu for Logged In Users
        $args['menu'] = "name-of-user-menu";
        return $args;           
    }   else { 
    // Default Menu
        return $args;       
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works but is there way to rename page title in menu for specific user group?

Comment: You can do this by using a filter with `the_title` Have a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

Comment: I did but it change every page to 'Dashbord'(that i wan to change with) do you have a right example about it

Answer (score 0):

You use non existing function `is_user_login`. You need to use `is_user_logged_in()` instead.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() )
    wp_nav_menu(...);
else
    wp_nav_menu(...);
```

Comment: I know I change it but I mean I want some pages hide from some users in navigate menu